# sort table or list in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hope I can help.

I been trying to implement some form of sort my search results, but it and succeeded.

I'm using Rails 2.8.3, because the application is made well, and I'll just edit that part of ordering.

I need something exactly that in episode # 228 railscast but the method "ORDER"does not exist in this version and I mark error.

Try the plugin: [handles_sortable_columns](https://github.com/dadooda/handles_sortable_columns) but I could not configure it.

I am new to this I would like to help.

## Basic Usage

controller

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
    handles_sortable_columns

       def index
    order = sortable_column_order
    if params[:search]
       @ads = Ad.search(params[:search], params[:page], :order=>order)
    else
      @ads = Ad.paginate :per_page => 4, :page => params[:page], :order => order
    end
  end
...
```

index view

```
<%= sortable_column "zone" %>
<%= sortable_column "Price" %>
```

model

```
def self.search(search, page,sort)
 paginate :per_page => 4, :page => page,:conditions => [-here conditions and values-]
end
```

when parameters are empty search also works, and the order also works only when I search for orders in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should or migrate to Rails 3.0.x or use `:order` option.

So show what and how you want to order. Show your code.

Comment: That is in long-term plan as it is an extensive application and what would be ideal in a short time is just change this part of ordering.